# Не хочет подключать драйвер для MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных

Ловлю

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at game.Main.main(Main.java:19)

Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'.
> Process 'command '/snap/intellij-idea-ultimate/181/jbr/bin/java'' 
finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

при попытке исполнить

```
import game.gamefield.GameField;
import game.gamefield.StateFormatException;
import game.gamelogic.Logic;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws StateFormatException, ClassNotFoundException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

    String name = "username";
    String password = "mypass";
    String connectionUrl = "myurl";
    String driver   = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    Class.forName(driver);

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, name, password)) {
        System.out.println("We are Connected");
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка подключения к серверу!");

    }

    Logic lg = new Logic(new GameField());
    lg.start();
}
}
```

значения переменных само собой при попытке запуска иные.
для сборки используется gradle

Comment: А ты добавил [драйвер](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) в проект? [Как](https://metanit.com/java/database/2.1.php) установить драйвер.

Comment: да, вот https://i.imgur.com/E3bGCHC.png . и так и сяк пробовал

Comment: дык у тебя же Classpath красным подсвечивает.

Comment: это просто подсветка выбранного элемента